# Slide sidebar into view on mouse click

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I'm trying to create my own toggleable sidebar. I've done this snippet (press the brown color in screen to toggle):

I'd like that the background had the full width of the screen so when i hit on the brown part, the background is brown,not white.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rest-of-the-page").click(
    function() {
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("hidden");

    }
  );
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: rgba(27, 26, 26, .8);
  transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}
.hidden {
  margin-left: -30%;
  transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}
#logo-container {
  min-height: 150px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1A1A1A;
}
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(Images/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 75% auto;
}
.menu-options-container {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-options-ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70%;
}
#menu-options-ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #373737;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #999;
  display: table;
}
#menu-options-ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
#menu-options-ul li p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-options-ul li p:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#rest-of-the-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: antiquewhite
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="logo-container">
      <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-options-container">
      <ul id="menu-options-ul">
        <li>
          <p>Hola</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Adios</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Buenas</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rest-of-the-page"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a class with left:0 name it "*fullpage*"

make the width 100% for **#rest-of-the-page**

```
#rest-of-the-page{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    left:15%;
    height:100%;
    transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    cursor:pointer;  
    background-color:antiquewhite
}
#rest-of-the-page.fullpage{
     left:0;
}
```

**UPDATE** : Another thing make the margin-left : -15% and not -30% because the width of the sidebar is only 15%

```
.hidden{ 
    margin-left: -15%;
    transition: all .2s linear 0s; //you don't need this
}
```

add overflow hidden to body

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

toggleClass fullpage for **#rest-of-the-page**

https://jsfiddle.net/yggt4s83/2/

Comment: Thanks. But here the white space can be seen during the animation.

Comment: Now it's perfect! I cannot mark your post as answer but i'll upvote you mate. Thanks!

Comment: You're right. I changed the answer of the question. Yours is best!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the background color of the #rest-of-the-page element to your body:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rest-of-the-page").click(
    function() {
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("hidden");

    }
  );
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: antiquewhite
}
.container {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: rgba(27, 26, 26, .8);
  transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}
.hidden {
  margin-left: -30%;
  transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}
#logo-container {
  min-height: 150px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1A1A1A;
}
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(Images/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 75% auto;
}
.menu-options-container {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-options-ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70%;
}
#menu-options-ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #373737;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #999;
  display: table;
}
#menu-options-ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
#menu-options-ul li p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-options-ul li p:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#rest-of-the-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: antiquewhite
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="logo-container">
      <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-options-container">
      <ul id="menu-options-ul">
        <li>
          <p>Hola</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Adios</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Buenas</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rest-of-the-page"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. With this approach, could I have a different background color for the body depending on the page I am?

Comment: Sure, you'd just need to change the color as needed.

Comment: So it will be overridden right? I'm trying to understand how CSS works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's kind of a broad question to answer without more details. How CSS renders depends on its [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Overriding rules is usually easy, but sometimes you're left scratching your head wondering why something isn't working, and it's usually due to specificity.

Comment: I've tried it and seems to work as I want. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: this a wrong solution, if you have a content in the rest of the page it will not move to the left like we expect

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add or remove a class on your #Rest-of-page when you toggle your menu ? Like that, your content will always stick to right side of the page if you have some. No tricky things using absolute position etc involved.

Just like this, ( exemple [here](http://codepen.io/AxelCardinaels/pen/KpJmdK) )

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="logo-container">
            <div id= "logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-options-container">
            <ul id="menu-options-ul">
                <li><p>Hola</p></li>
                <li><p>Adios</p></li>
                <li><p>Buenas</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="rest-of-the-page" class="page--sided"><p>Hello</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.container{
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(27, 26, 26, .8);
    transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.hidden{

    margin-left: -30%;
    transition: all .2s linear 0s;
}

#logo-container {
    min-height: 150px;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #1A1A1A;
}

#logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:url(Images/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 75% auto;
}

.menu-options-container {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-options-ul{
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
    height:70%;
}

#menu-options-ul li{

    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #373737;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
    height:3em;
    margin-top:0;
    color: #999;
    display: table;
}

#menu-options-ul li:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}


#menu-options-ul li p{

    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-options-ul li p:hover{

    color: #fff;
}

#rest-of-the-page{

    height:100%;
    transition: all .2s linear 0s;
    cursor:pointer;  
    background-color:antiquewhite
}

.page--sided{
  position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:15%;
    width: 85%;
}


.page--full{
  width:100%;
}
```

JS :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#rest-of-the-page").click(
                function () {
                    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("hidden");

                    if ($("#rest-of-the-page").hasClass("page--sided")){
                      $("#rest-of-the-page").removeClass("page--sided")
                      $("#rest-of-the-page").addClass("page--full");
                    }else{
                      $("#rest-of-the-page").addClass("page--sided")
                      $("#rest-of-the-page").removeClass("page--full");
                    }


                }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = true;
 function show(sidebar){
if(a==true){
  sidebar.style.left = "0px";
  sidebar.style.transition  = "left 0.6s linear";
  a=false;
 }
 else{
  sidebar.style.left = "-200px";
  sidebar.style.transition  = "left 0.6s linear";
  a=true;
 }
 }
```

```css
body{

 margin: 0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family: helvetica;
}

#sidebar{
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #151718;
 top:0px;
 left:-200px;
 position: absolute;
}

#sidebar ul{
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar ul li{
 list-style: none;
}

#sidebar ul li a{
 color:white;
 padding:10px;
 width: 180px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#btn{
 margin: 20px;
 padding:20px;
 right: -90px;
 position: absolute;
}

#btn span{
 background: black;
 width: 25px;
 height:5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: block;
    border-radius:17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

<div id="btn" onclick="show(sidebar)">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Vk</a></li>

<li><a href="#">google</a></li>

<li><a href="#">ymail</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**Html left Sidebar using CSS and Javascript **